# Starling Recreation of new Objects when a decision is made

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, object, actionscript

Creating a point and touch game, whenever the user clicks on something that is interactive it will display a decision wheel that gives 3 choices. Action, chat or examine. I have centralised everything around a main touch handler. So if it is an interactive object create a new decision wheel and add a listener for when a decision is made, to then call proceed With Decision. Before it is shown I add a dark overlay so that the user cannot tamper with anything on the screen until a decision is made.

Any suggestions on a better approach to this? Obviously I know creating a new object every time, then calling removeFromParent(true) every time it's finished with, is a bad idea for performance.

The object being passed in contains attributes of the object that was touched. Such as the id and x and y position so I know where to position the decision wheel on the screen.

My main question:
How to set it up so I only have one decision object instead of having to re-create a new instance every time something is touched?

```
override protected function createDecisionWheel(object:Object):void
    {
        if (!GameState.AWAITING_DECISION) {

            //create bg overlay
            _overlay = new Overlay();
            addChild(_overlay);

            //waiting for decision from user
            GameState.AWAITING_DECISION = true;

            _decisionWheel = new DecisionWheel(object);
            addChild(_decisionWheel);

            _decisionWheel.x = _decisionWheel.positionDecisionWheelX(object._x, _backgroundPosition);
            _decisionWheel.y = _decisionWheel.positionDecisionWheelY(object._y, _backgroundPosition);

            addEventListener("DecisionMade", proceedWithDecision);
        }
    }

    override protected function proceedWithDecision(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener("DecisionMade", proceedWithDecision);

        //remove once decision has been made @TODO
        _decisionWheel.removeDecisionWheel();
        _overlay.removeOverlay();

        //reset
        GameState.AWAITING_DECISION = false;

        trace("proceed with decision");
    }
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking for. Are you asking about touchable = false?

Comment: updated the post with a main question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a member variable:

```
private var _decisionWheel:DecisionWheel;
```

in your constructor:

```
_decisionWheel = new DecisionWheel(object);
addChild(_decisionWheel);
_decisionWheel.visible = false;
```

Then just toggle _decisionWheel.visible - when making decision:

```
_decisionWheel.visible = true;
_decisionWheel.x = _decisionWheel.positionDecisionWheelX(object._x, _backgroundPosition);
_decisionWheel.y = _decisionWheel.positionDecisionWheelY(object._y, _backgroundPosition);
// and watever more mapping you need to add
```

Then proceed with decision:

```
_decisionWheel.visible = true;
```

Note that if you want to use removeFromParent, make sure you do removeFromParent(false) so your object is not disposed.